# Fast random to unique relabeling of numpy 2d regions (without loops)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have a large numpy 2d array (10000,10000) in which regions (clusters of cells with the same number) are randomly labeled. As a result, some separate regions were assigned to the same label. What I would like is to relabel the numpy 2d array so that all separate regions are assigned to a unique label (see example).

I now how to solve this problem with a loop. But as I am working with a large array with a lot of small regions, this process takes ages. Therefore, a vectorized approach would be more suitable.

Example:

-Two separate regions are labeled with 1
-Two separate regions are
   labeled with 3

```
## Input
random_arr=np.array([[1,1,3,3],[1,2,2,3],[2,2,1,1],[3,3,3,1]])
```

[image: random]

```
## Apply function
unique_arr=relabel_regions(random_arr)
## Output
>>> unique_arr
array([[1, 1, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 4]])
```

[image: unique]

Slow solution with loop:

```
def relabel_regions(random_regions):
    # Locate random regions index
    random_labs=np.unique(random_regions)

    unique_segments=np.zeros(np.shape(random_regions),dtype='uint64')
    count=0
    kernel=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]],dtype='uint8')
    # Assign unique number to each random labeled region
    for i in range(len(random_labs)):
        mask=np.zeros(np.shape(random_regions))
        mask[np.where(random_regions==random_labs[i])]=1
        labeled_mask, freq = ndimage.label(mask, structure=kernel)
        labeled_mask=labeled_mask+count
        unique_segments[np.where(labeled_mask>0+count)]=labeled_mask[np.where(labeled_mask>0+count)]
        count+=freq
    return unique_segments
```

Comment: If you simply count the number of regions and then for each region assign its number, no region will be assigned to the same label twice. (I am missing something here?)

Comment: Post your solution with the loop ;) How do you *randomly* assign labels ? Can't you condition the assignment from the beginning ?

Comment: @NikolasRieble The number of regions in the first picture is 3, So how wil it be possible to relabel them from 1 to 5?

Comment: @FloranGmehlin I do not assign the random labels, this is the output of another function from another program to which I do not have access. I will add the solution with a loop

Comment: Ah okay. region = clusters of cells with the same number, area = neighbours of cells with the same number. Now I understand, you have no problem in counting the areas, you are asking for a faster way.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Exactly, I am asking for a faster way to relabel regions with multipe areas, so that all areas are assigned to an unique number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's cheat and just use some high-quality library ([scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/)) which offers exactly this.

You may learn from it's implementation or just use it!

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label

random_arr = np.array([[1,1,3,3],[1,2,2,3],[2,2,1,1],[3,3,3,1]])
labels = label(random_arr, connectivity=1)  # neighborhood-definition here!

print(labels)
```

#### Output

```
[[1 1 2 2]
 [1 3 3 2]
 [3 3 4 4]
 [5 5 5 4]]
```

**EDIT:** Like mentioned by Jeon in the comments, scipy's [scipy.ndimage.measurements.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) might also be a candidate if one does not want to use one more extra library! Thanks for the comment Jeon!

Comment: I was thinking almost same thing. I was trying to use `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know skimage also had this function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jeon Interesting, that scipy seems to offer the same. I was just researching for connect-components implementations and stumbled upon scikit-image's function used above. The scipy-approach might be interesting for people wanting to minimize library usage (despite the fact that if you got scipy to work it should be more easy to do the same for scikit-image).

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting for me, too. I realized that scikit is based on scipy. So far, I haven't used scikit because I thought scikit is a competitor of scipy. That's my misunderstanding.

Comment: Most quality libraries use scipy internally. I never saw scikit-image as a competitor, but it's interesting to see that there are still some overlaps (the whole ```scipy.ndimage``` part). I was also under the impression that all scikit-projects are somehow connected to th numpy/scipy stack.